# Binding in JavaFX 2.0

Tags: java, data-binding, javafx-2, javafx

Maybe I missunderstood JavaFX binding or there is a bug in SimpleStringProperty.

When I run this testcode my changed model value didn't get the new value. Test testBindingToModel fails. I thought my model should then be updated with the value of the TextField tf. But only the binding value of prop1Binding gets the value "test".

```
public class BindingTest {  
    private TextField tf;
    private Model model;
    private ModelBinding mb;

    @Before
    public void prepare() {
        tf = new TextField();
        model = new Model();
        mb = new ModelBinding(model);
        Bindings.bindBidirectional(tf.textProperty(), mb.prop1Binding);
    }

    @Test
    public void testBindingToMB() {
        tf.setText("test");

        assertEquals(tf.getText(), mb.prop1Binding.get());
    }

    @Test
    public void testBindingToModel() {
        tf.setText("test");

        assertEquals(tf.getText(), mb.prop1Binding.get());
        assertEquals(tf.getText(), model.getProp1());
    }

    private static class ModelBinding {
        private final StringProperty prop1Binding;

        public ModelBinding(Model model) {
            prop1Binding = new SimpleStringProperty(model, "prop1");
        }

    }

    private static class Model {
        private String prop1;

        public String getProp1() {
            return prop1;
        }

        public void setProp1(String prop1) {
            this.prop1 = prop1;
        }       
    }
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Best regards
Sebastian

EDIT:
With this class I can set the value of the model directly. I will test this class in the next days and comment on this post with my result.

```
public class MySimpleStringProperty extends SimpleStringProperty {
    public MySimpleStringProperty(Object obj, String name) {
        super(obj, name);
    }

    public MySimpleStringProperty(Object obj, String name, String initVal) {
        super(obj, name, initVal);
    }

    @Override
    public void set(String arg0) {
        super.set(arg0);
        if (this.getBean() != null) {
            try {
                Field f = this.getBean().getClass().getDeclaredField(this.getName());
                f.setAccessible(true);
                f.set(this.getBean(), arg0);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                // logging here
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // logging here
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // logging here
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // logging here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured out that there is provided the class JavaBeanStringProperty, which just fullfill my request.

Using this code I can directly bind the value of my bean to a StringProperty (included setting and getting of my value to / from my Bean).

```
binding = JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder.create().beanClass(Model.class).bean(model).name("prop1").build();
```

The only problem I found is that when you change the value of the model after setting the binding, there is no update e.g. in the TextField.

Answer (score 2):

This constructor doesn't attach `SimpleStringProperty` to a bean object unfortunately. It just says to `SimpleStringProperty` which bean property belongs to.

E.g., if you want to have a property in your class you should do it next way:

```
public static class Model {

    private StringProperty prop1 = 
          new SimpleStringProperty(this, "prop1", "default_value");

    public String getProp1() {
        return prop1.get();
    }

    public void setProp1(String value) {
        prop1.set(value);
    }

    public StringProperty prop1Property() {
        return prop1;
    }
}
```

Note, that there is no way to bind to your original `Model` class as it provides no events about setting new `prop1` value. If you want to have observable model, you should use fx properties from the beginning.

Comment: Hi,
thanks for your answer. Did they just forget the option to set the value directly? For example I didn't want to have my model mixed up with JavaFX Properties.
I updated my question with an fix for the problem, which solves the problem for me. Is there more I have to consider if I want to bind my model direct?